# Dependency Graphs similar to VS 2010 Ultimate?

Tags: .net, dependencies, uml, code-visualization

I'm looking for a visualization tool for net code dependency graphs similar to Dependency Graphs feature of VS 2010 Ultimate.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847415.aspx

Since VS 2010 Ultimate is not available on my project, i'd like to use a similar third party tool, preferably an open-source.

The features i expect from a tool are:

- Dependencies in multiple assemblies
- Visualization
- Filtering
- Navigation
- Detalization levels (assembly, namespace, class/interface, member)
- Go to sourcecode (preferrably a VS2008 integration)

Please recommend the tools known to be good at some of the points listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Dependencies in multiple assemblies
- Visualization
- Filtering
- Navigation
- Detalization levels (assembly, namespace, class/interface, member)
- Go to sourcecode (preferrably a VS2008 integration)

Indeed, I confirm, NDepend has all of them (I am the NDepend lead dev).

Here is the documentation detailing [NDepend Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx) in details

[image]

NDepend has also a [Dependency Structure Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx) that will help dig ino more complex graph
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) has all that and more, but is neither free nor open source.